# Error "String is not a valid Base64-encoded string" while mounting Azure blob storage to Databricks using dbutils.fs.mount and dbutils.secrets.get

Tags: azure, databricks, mount

I'm following the documentation here to mount an Azure blob storage container to Databricks:

https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/data-sources/mount-azure-blob-storage.html

However, I get an error while attempting this.

Here is my code:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://log@my-storage.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/log/",
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.my-storage.blob.core.windows.net": dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "my-scope", key = "my-key")}
)
```

Here is the error:

```
shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The String is not a valid Base64-encoded string.
```

I am able to just run dbutils.secrets.get to retrieve the secret like so:

```
dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "my-scope", key = "my-key")
```

Output:

```
Out[12]: '[REDACTED]'
```

I expect this since it should not print the secret to the output. However, I would think I would get a permissions error or the like if I was not able to pass this value through to the extra_configs parameter.

Also, I am able to mount it easily if I directly insert the access key into the extra_configs parameter like so:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://log@my-storage.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/log/",
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.my-storage.blob.core.windows.net": "my-access-key")}
)
```

The problem is I can do this in DEV, but need to pass the secret instead in the upper environments.

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow below steps:**

**Step 1:** **Create Azure key vault and save Secrets name with access key:**

[image]

**Step 2:** Create [Secret scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope-using-the-ui) and also please follow this syntax for creating secret scope in azure Databricks:
`https://<Azure_databricks_instance>#secrets/createScope` and save DNS name and resource ID.

[image]

[image]

**Create mount:**

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://<container_name>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/<mount_data>",
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<Storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope_name>", key = "scrate_key")})
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is exactly the process that I performed already.

Comment: Hi @TerriS, Please remove `/log` at mount folder location. follow this syntax `/mnt/<mount_data>`. try once's.

Comment: Hi @BhanunagasaiVamsi, tried it and I received the same error.

Comment: This error usually occurs when the access key format is invalid, hence unable to parse the base64 encoded string

Comment: Did you figure out.. I get the same error and there is no space in my Key